# Receiving ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ActivityNotification::NotificationsWithDeviseController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently trying to implement **activity_notification** gem. The issue I am having, is the gem is searching for the **user_id**, but I have implemented friendly_id and the gem is unable to find the user. The parameters show `{"target_type"=>"users", "devise_type"=>"users", "user_id"=>"dannytom222"}` and then the gem fails with **Couldn't find User**. I'm using the predefined controller for the gem, and cannot locate the method that is throwing this error.
In my stack trace, it shows

```
      def find_by!(*args) # :nodoc:
        find_by(*args) || raise(RecordNotFound.new("Couldn't find #{name}", name))
      end
```

Full trace

```
activerecord (5.1.5) lib/active_record/core.rb:228:in `find_by!'
activity_notification (1.4.4) lib/activity_notification/controllers/common_controller.rb:28:in `set_target'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:197:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in `block in halting'
```

friendly_id for user.rb

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :username, use: :slugged
```

migration file for friendly_id slug

```
class AddSlugToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :slug, :string
    add_index :users, :slug, unique: true
  end
end
```

How can I get activity_notification to accept the username attribute, in place of the user_id?

UPDATE:
I changed the link_to method to 
`<%= link_to 'Notifications' user_notifications_path(current_user.id) %>` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to user `user.friendly_id` or however, you have declared it to your model instead of `user.id`. This seems to the issue

Comment: I updated my question with the configuration that I have for friendly_id. I'm going to try to use current_user.id instead of current_user by itself.